# Return to sourceApplication after openUrl request is completely handled

Tags: ios

I'm implementing an iOS app that handles a custom protocol.
Writing the method application(openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:) in my AppDelegate was easy but I'm left with a problem: I want that - once the user have done with the request - my app move to the background and send the user back to the caller sourceApplication (e.g. a browser, a QRCode reader, or any another app).

This is just like the difference between "tel:" and "telprompt:" url calls: in the former case the phone app remains active, in the latter case, after the call, the user is send back to the sourceApplication.

In order to let my app handle my custom protocol like "telprompt:" does, the only way I can think about is terminate the app once the user action is completed... but this is against iOS Human Interface Guidelines (they say "Don’t Quit Programmatically") and my app can be rejected by Apple.

On Android it is easy: you respond to an Intent with an Activity and when you call finish() on that activity the user is back to his previous app/browser/whatever.

Anyone knows a good way to achieve this on iOS?

Just to clarify:

- my app don't call openUrl, it responds to openUrl requests from browser, QRCode reader, other apps;
- I don't have to make phone calls;
- when I handle a request I ask the user for some data, contact a server, and that's it: the interaction is finished and it would be very nice to drive the user back to previous app without let him use the home button.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should call openUrl when you are done, with the source app url in param.

That's what facebook does when you use the "connect with facebook" API.

Comment: It's not working. Eg. when my app is called via a web page open in safari I receive sourceApplication = "com.apple.mobilesafari". Then I tried to call openUrl with "com.apple.mobilesafari", "com.apple.mobilesafari:", or even  "com.apple.mobilesafari://" but none of them works.